# Publish DB updates remotely to Meteor

Tags: json, rest, meteor, parameters

Suppose I have a Mongo DB database in Meteor, let's say for books.

ISBN | Title | Year

Now updating this fields from Meteor is no big deal, but suppose I want another web application to publish new books that the has to go into the Mongo DB.

For example the publishing app can call a web address like this:

How can I handle this http request from Meteor please? Is there a library or known mechanism for this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to talk to the MongoDB directly from your other app, then you don't need anything from Meteor: when the DB is updated, Meteor will see the changes.

If you mean 'how can I build a REST API through my Meteor App?' 
then you could have a look at packages like `simple:rest` or `restivus`

https://atmospherejs.com/simple/rest

https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus

This allows you to access your Publications or Methods through http calls like you would with a REST API.

collection `books` could be called with 
http://myapp.com/publications/books

With Methods you can handle POST, UPDATE and DELETE verbs.